# having trouble using nextafter C++ stl

Tags: c++, floating-point, std, cmath

This seems a bit strange to me, so please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I need to use the `std::nextafter` function. As explained here: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter

The header I need to include is `<cmath>`.

I was able to use this quite simply here: http://cpp.sh/4z4hw

But if I now use the same code in Visual Studio(2015 compiler v110), compilation fails, and says that nextafter is not a member of std.

I am not sure how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Using C++11.

The code I use is attached.

Please also note that I also use std::ceil, std::floor and that is also a member of cmath, but that seems to work fine.

```
float ConfigEngine::adjustRenderRegionVal(int heightOrWidth, float 
  rrVal, uint expectedValue, uint calculatedValue, bool isMin)
 {
    if (calculatedValue < expectedValue)
         rrVal = std::nextafter(rrVal, 1.0f);
    else //is greater
        rrVal = std::nextafter(rrVal, -1.0f);

    uint newRRLowPx;
    if (isMin)
        newRRLowPx = static_cast<uint>(std::floor(rrVal * heightOrWidth));
    else
         newRRLowPx = static_cast<uint>(std::ceil(rrVal * heightOrWidth));

     if (newRRLowPx != expectedValue)
         return adjustRenderRegionVal(heightOrWidth, rrVal, expectedValue, newRRLowPx, isMin);//recursive call

     return rrVal;
}
```

Comment: Not everything in the standard library is a part of STL (standard template library).

Comment: VS2019 supports it fine so perhaps upgrading is the easiest option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo updating is not an option for me, is there an alternate?

Comment: Well, you could put these parts of the code in a DLL that you create with `VS2019` that you then use in this VS2015 project.

Comment: I found another solution.. I looked at the std code, it internally calls _nextafter. _nextafter is supported by VS2015 if I include <float.h>. Thank You @TedLyngmo for pointing me in the right direction